# Jupyter Notebook: Git Files

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I’m trying to populate my Sagemaker EC2 instance with scripts/modules from my git repo for running Jupyter notebooks.

When I clone the git repo using access token, I get a repo.git file in my Jupyter directory where notebooks live.

What do I do with this file and how do I Import the py files from the repo? My goal is to actually have the files in my local instance and navigate through them(vs a single flat .git file)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @mkrieger1. Thanks for your reply.  Not quite. I am able to see the repository file .git in my location but I don’t know how to access it

Comment: By doing what it says in the accepted answer to the question I've linked. The repo.git file (it should actually be a directory) is a *bare repository*. If you clone from it again, you get a normal repository.

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger. In my git config file, I set bare = false and I also changed my directory, which solved the problem.